# Dense sequence definition

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

A subset $A$ of a space $X$ is called dense if every point $x$ in $X$ either belongs to $A$ or is a limit point of $A$ ; that is, the closure of $A$ constitutes the whole set $X$.

That the definition of a dense set, what about sequences? what is the meaning of dense sequence?

Comment: I’d need more context to be sure, but I expect that it’s a sequence $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ in $X$ whose underlying set, $\{x_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$, is dense in $X$.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A sequence is not dense. It’s a common abuse of terminology that identifies the sequence, which is a function from the natural numbers to the real numbers (usually), with its image set, which is a subset of the codomain of the sequence.

A sequence $(x_n)_{n}$ is a function from the natural numbers to a set $X$ and, formally, can be written as $(x_n)_{n} \in X^{\mathbb{N}}$. The image of any function is a subset of the codomain, and so we write $\{x_n : n \in\mathbb{N}\}$. Hence, to be precise, we should say that the image set of the sequence is dense in $X$, that is $\overline{\{x_n : n \in\mathbb{N}\}}=X$

The same Rudin, Principles of Mathematical Analysis, definition 2.7: "By a sequence, we mean a function $f$ defined on the set $J$ of all positive integers".

Comment: The sequence of the rational numbers is a dense sequence in the set of the real numbers.

Comment: The image of the sequence of the rational numbers is a dense SET in the set of the real numbers.

Comment: There is no image of the sequence of the rational numbers. Some dense sets are countable, and then it is customary to call them "sequences". You may start a new semantic trend, if you wish, but that will not prevent the rationals from being a dense sequence.

Comment: Rudin, Principles of Mathematical Analysis, definition 2.7: "By a sequence, we mean a function $f$ defined on the set $J$ of all positive integers". No more than that :)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I read this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4045907/uniform-distribution-of-points-on-a-sphere related to dense sequence, I did not understand this statement "it follows easily that the closure of all products of A and B is the whole group of rotations of the sphere"! if you can clarify it for me that will be great. Thanks

Comment: Roughly looking at it, also here you can think about the images of the operators A and B. Keep in mind, as long as you take set operations (and closure is one of them), you are talking about sets

Comment: What is the meaning of -1!! Is the answer wrong? I'm new here.

Comment: @uniquesolution was only upset that and, only by anger, he downvoted to seem my answer not correct. Instead of helping us, he (or she) just downvoted.

Answer (score 2):

A sequence can be viewed as a set by forgetting the order of the elements. The sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is dense if the set $\{x_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ is dense.

Answer (score -1):

A sequence is dense if the set whose elements are the sequence elements, is dense according to your definition.